# master_not_discovered_exception - Error when setting up multi node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried configuring multi node cluster using aws EC2 instance. I created 3 instances and made one as master node and other two as data node. but when I hit the public IP of master node it gave me response that’s mean its working but even if I hit the public IP of data nodes also it gave me response so through the security groups I set the inbound rules for the data nodes it can only access by master node. [ port 9200 - 9300 source publicIPofMaster/32 ] but after this change in security group also am getting response if I hit the public IP of master node ( publicIP:9200 ) but getting an error if I hit `publicIP:9200/_cluster/health`

error is

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason": null
      }
    ],
    "type": "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason": null
  },
  "status": 503
}
```

how can I fix this. data nodes should not be accessible from outside no ?? it should only be accessible by master node. thats why I made the change in security group.

data node -2: -

```yaml
cluster.name: Cluster-Presentation 
node.name: node-2 
network.host: 172.31.34.104 
discovery.seed_hosts:["172.31.34.104","172.31.40.191","172.31.38.85"] 
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["172.31.38.85"] 
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

data node -1: -

```yaml
cluster.name: Cluster-Presentation 
node.name: node-3 
network.host: 172.31.40.191 
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.31.34.104","172.31.40.191","172.31.38.85"] 
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["172.31.38.85"] 
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

master node:-

```yaml
cluster.name: Cluster-Presentation 
node.name: node-1 
network.host: 172.31.38.85 
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.31.34.104","172.31.40.191","172.31.38.85"] 
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["172.31.38.85"] 
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: This issue seems to mean your `data nodes` are not able to communicate with the `master node`

Comment: please share elasticsearch.yml of three nodes.

Comment: data node -2: -

cluster.name: Cluster-Presentation
node.name: node-2
network.host: 172.31.34.104
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.31.34.104","172.31.40.191","172.31.38.85"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["172.31.38.85"]
xpack.security.enabled: false

data node -1: -

cluster.name: Cluster-Presentation
node.name: node-3
network.host: 172.31.40.191
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.31.34.104","172.31.40.191","172.31.38.85"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["172.31.38.85"]
xpack.security.enabled: false

Comment: master node:-

cluster.name: Cluster-Presentation
node.name: node-1
network.host: 172.31.38.85
discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.31.34.104","172.31.40.191","172.31.38.85"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["172.31.38.85"]
xpack.security.enabled: false

Comment: @Paulo yes thats the error how I can fix that error

Comment: Please put the information in your question not in the comments :D

Comment: Added the yml configs in the queastion :D

Comment: I opened all the required ports in the SG aswell

Comment: discovery.seed_hosts: ["172.31.38.85"] is enough. restart and tell me what happen when you call 172.31.38.85:9200/_cat/health?v .

Comment: what is the difference between discovery.seed_hosts and cluster.initial_master_nodes in both settings we are configuring master eligible nodes no ??